# Loading vector tile layer in Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles, mapillary

I need to load a vector tile layer in a Leaflet map.

The vector tile is the vector tile layer about Mapillary sequences (look at https://a.mapillary.com/#vector-tiles ...), and the tile URL pattern is:

```
https://d2munx5tg0hw47.cloudfront.net/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.mapbox
```

the vector tile use the Mapbox vector tile format.

I've searched on the net but I haven't found a sample: I've seen that this could be done using Mapbox, but if it's possible I'd like to use only Leaflet

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Leaflet 0.7x, this is made easy with the [`Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile` plugin](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile). You just need to specify the URL pattern in the `url` configuration option. The plugin documentation details the [other configuration options](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile/blob/master/docs/configuration.md) that are available. To add the Mapillary data, you would use it like this:

```js
var config = {
  url: "https://d2munx5tg0hw47.cloudfront.net/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.mapbox"
};
var mapillarySource = new L.TileLayer.MVTSource(config);
map.addLayer(mapillarySource);
```

Here is a fiddle showing the result:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/sj12o4hj/

For Leaflet 1.0x, you will want to use [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.VectorGrid)'s `L.vectorGrid.protobuf` method. It has a number of [styling options](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.VectorGrid#styling) described in the docs, but for just loading the tiles, you would use it like this:

```js
var url = 'https://d2munx5tg0hw47.cloudfront.net/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.mapbox';
var mapillaryLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(url).addTo(map);
```

Example fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/mwmpmLo7/

Comment: Great!! it's working. Simple, clear and with example. The best!

Comment: @nathansnider Your JSFiddle is not reachable. Would love a proper example on how to read vector-based tiles with leaflet

Comment: Anything for Leaflet v3+ react + typescript?

Comment: The plugin referred to here (`leaflet-mapbox-vector-tile`) has 21 weekly downloads in 2024 and was last published 9 years ago, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-mapbox-vector-tile

Comment: And the other plugin referred to here (`leaflet.vectorgrid`) has 5980 weekly downloads in 2024 and was last published 7 years ago, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.vectorgrid

Answer (score 6):

See the list of [Leaflet plugins for vector tiles](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#vector-tiles). Note that MapboxVectorTile and hoverboard work only with Leaflet 0.7.x, which will be deprecated by Leaflet 1 "Really Soon™".